# How do I create a dictionary with input symbols as keys and ascii codes as values?

Tags: python, dictionary, ord

I'm making a dictionary in which the keys will be one-character symbols separates by a space that the user inputs. I'm assuming that I have call the ord value in a separate line but I'm not sure how to correctly phrase it. Below is the code I have currently:

```py
inp = input()

inp = inp.split(" ")

d = dict.fromkeys(inp, ord(inp))

print(d)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

A [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension) would give you what you want:

```py
inp = input()
d = {x: ord(x) for x in inp}
print(d)
```

This iterates through the string `inp` and constructs the key/value pairs from the iterator, `x`, and `ord(x)`.

This doesn't remove spaces, as you seem to possibly be after by `inp.split(" ")`, but I interpreted this as your attempt to split the string by character. Should you want to remove spaces, remove them from the `inp` object.

Comment: Also its a good idea to `inp.strip()` in the case of input separeted by spaces

Comment: `.strip()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace @jvx8ss - not whitespace in the middle. If spaces (or any other character) aren't desired they need to be replaced `{x: ord(x) for x in inp.replace(' ', '')}` or ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I converted the input with the split function into a list. Then I added the inputs with the `ord()` function to an empty list with the append function. Then i created a dictionary called `d` and combined the two lists with using the `zip()` function. In this way, created a dictionary with the single characters I entered and their ord value.

```
inp = input()
inp = inp.split(" ")
ordinput = []
for i in inp:
  x = ord(i)
  ordinput.append(x)
d = dict(zip(inp, ordinput))
print(d)
```

Comment: The ord() function returns the number representing the unicode code of a specified ** character**.

a solution this problem with zip func.

Comment: Please provide more supporting information with your answer.

Comment: I converted the input with the split function into a list.
Then i added the inputs  with the ord() function to an empty list with the append function.
Then i created a dictionary called d and combined the two lists with  using the zip() function.
In this way, created a dictionary with the single characters I entered and their ord value.